# Oracle SQL random value from string set

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

In Oracle SQL 11g I am trying to fill a table with procedure. For some columns I need to take data randomly from predefined set of strings. How do I define such set and take data from it by random order?

Comment: "Predefined set of strings" sounds like "a table" to me. DBMS_RANDOM is a standard package in Oracle which contains functions that return random numbers. Best of luck.

Comment: Isn't there a way to create the set as a variable like in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a cte and `dbms_random.value`.  Something like:

```
with strings as (
      select 'string1' as s from dual union all
      select 'string2' as s from dual union all
      select 'string3' as s from dual union all
      select 'string4' as s from dual
     )
select <col1>,
       (select s
        from (select s from strings order by dbms_random.value) s
        where rownum = 1
       ) as RandomString
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a try,it is working.

1.Insert the list of strings in a table (strings).

2.Create a function(RANDOM) to generate random number.

3.Create a procedure(PROC_STRING) to pick a string name from (STRINGS) table using the random  number generated from function(RANDOM) and then insert into (NEW_TABLE)

**PROGRAM:**

```
 --Table  with list of string names 
    Create table strings (string_id  number,string_name varchar2(2000) );

    --Table to store new string names in random order
    Create table new_table (string_id  number,string_name varchar2(2000) );

--Function to generate random numbers
create or replace  function random(p_number in number)
    return number
    is
    a number;
    begin
   select dbms_random.value(1,10) into a
    from dual;
    a := floor(a);
   return a;
    end;
    /

delete from strings;
delete from new_table;

insert into strings values(1,'abc');
insert into strings values(2,'def');
insert into strings values(3,'ghi');

insert into strings values(4,'abc 1');
insert into strings values(5,'def 1');
insert into strings values(6,'ghi 1');

insert into strings values(7,'abc 2');
insert into strings values(8,'def 2');
insert into strings values(9,'ghi 2');

insert into strings values(10,'xyz 3');


--Procedure to  pick string names randomly from strings table and insert  into new_table
create or replace procedure proc_string(p_no in number)
as
s_id  number;
s_name varchar2(2000);
begin
select random(1) into s_id from dual;
select string_name into s_name from strings where string_id = s_id;
insert into New_table values(s_id,s_name);
dbms_output.put_line('insert successfully completed');
commit;
Exception when others
then dbms_output.put_line('ERROR:' || SQLCODE || ' ' || SQLERRM);
end;
/

commit;
```

**EXECUTION:**

```
--After executing the procedure for 3 times
SQL> exec proc_string(1);                                                                                                   
insert successfully completed 
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.                                                                                    

-- Random string names got inserted into newtable                                                                                                                           
SQL> select * from new_table;                                                                                        


STRING_ID STRING_NAME
5             def 1
3             ghi 
1             abc
```

Let me know if you questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am using the Gordon Linoff's solution. I have posted another sql problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418926/oracle-sql-illegal-year
I'd appreciate if you helped me with that.

Comment: Sure, Will try to help there.