# Oracle Sql illegal year

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In Oracle SQL developer 11g I am trying to generate a random date, assign it to a variable and later insert into a table. Date generate+assign to a variable code(which works fine):

```
DECLARE 
    Launch_date DATE;
      BEGIN
        Launch_date:=TO_DATE(TRUNC(
        DBMS_RANDOM.value(
        TO_CHAR(date '2000-01-01','J')
       ,TO_CHAR(date '2015-01-01','J')
        )),'J');
      END;
```

When trying to insert this to a table I get the following error message:

```
Error starting at line : 214 in command -
EXECUTE INSERT_DATA(15)
Error report -
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
ORA-06512: at "KALVAITYTE_INGRIDA.INSERT_DATA", line 43
ORA-06512: at line 1
01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
*Cause:    Illegal year entered
*Action:   Input year in the specified range
```

Here's the full code:

```
DROP TABLE ACCEPT_RESULT;
DROP TABLE DOCUMENTS;
DROP TABLE STUDENT;
DROP TABLE NEW_TABLE;
DROP SEQUENCE S_ACCEPT;
DROP SEQUENCE S_DOC;
DROP SEQUENCE S_STUD;

CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(ID_STUDENT NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
F_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
L_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
BORN_DATE DATE 
);

CREATE TABLE DOCUMENTS
(
DOC_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
ENTERED DATE,
FINISHED DATE,
ID_STUDENT NUMBER REFERENCES STUDENT(ID_STUDENT)
 );

CREATE TABLE ACCEPT_RESULT
(DETAIL_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
UNIVERSITY_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
FACULTY_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
DOC_ID NUMBER REFERENCES DOCUMENTS(DOC_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE
(
F_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
L_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
UNIVERSITY VARCHAR2(50),
FACULTY_NAME VARCHAR2(30)
);

INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('AGNĖ', 'AGNAITĖ', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('INGRIDA', 'INGRIDAITĖ', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('ANTANAS', 'ANTANAITIS', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('BRONIUS', 'BRONEVIČIUS', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('LIEPA', 'LIEPAITĖ', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('AGNĖ', 'TAUTAVIČIŪTĖ', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('ILONA', 'ŠILAITĖ', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('AKVILĖ', 'GEDRIMAITĖ', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('ANDRIUS', 'STONKUS', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('GRETA', 'GRETAITĖ', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('KASPARAS', 'NACIUS', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('ROKAS', 'DARGEVIČIUS', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('JUSTINAS', 'ENGELAITIS', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('VALIUS', 'DUMBRAUSKAS', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('EDGARAS', 'GVOZDAS', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('ANTANAS', 'JASAITIS', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('LINAS', 'STARKUTIS', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('AURIMAS', 'GEDMINTAS', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('LINAS', 'LINAITIS', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('LINAS', 'LINELIS', 'KLAIPĖDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('KRŪMAS', 'TADAS', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Mėlynas', 'Tadas', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Raudonas', 'Tomas', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Žalias', 'Karolis', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Geltonas', 'Robertas', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Oranžinis', 'Rokas', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Juodas', 'Justinas', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Pilkas', 'Ignas', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Dariauskas', 'Darius', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Kairys', 'Jurgis', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Dešinytė', 'Rūta', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Vyšniauskas', 'Petras', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Siemaitė', 'Aurelija', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Girtauskaitė', 'Ieva', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Piemenaitis', 'Audrius', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Grybas', 'Karolis', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Ekranavičius', 'Tomas', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Klavauskas', 'Antanas', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Žiurkytė', 'Sandra', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Kaleimauskas', 'Domas', 'KLAIPĖDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Blaivevičius',   'Haroldas', 'KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Pelytė', '   Aušra','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Meškaitė', ' Viktorija','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Vilkas', '   Kęstas','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Krūmas', '   Arūnas','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Medis', '    Artūras','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Obuolaitė', 'Ingrida','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Gaidauskienė', 'Eglė','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Žuvienė', 'Monika','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Morkavičius', 'Tadas','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Dešrytė', 'Kornelija','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Sūris', 'Aurimas','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Bandelė', 'Greta','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Rūkavičius', 'Edgaras','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Kreivauskas', 'Mantas','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Aklaitė', 'Diana','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Nekalbys', 'Rytis','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Telefonas', 'Deividas','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Lentaitė', 'Gabija','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Viniauskas', 'Hermanas','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('MALKA', 'TOMAS','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');


CREATE SEQUENCE S_STUD;
CREATE SEQUENCE S_DOC;
CREATE SEQUENCE S_ACCEPT;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_DATA(HOW_MANY_RECORDS NUMBER) IS
BEGIN

/*
1 TABLE STUDENT
*/

FOR I IN 1..HOW_MANY_RECORDS LOOP

DECLARE 
F_NAME_VALUE VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN

SELECT F_NAME INTO F_NAME_VALUE 
FROM
(SELECT F_NAME FROM NEW_TABLE
ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
WHERE rownum = 1;
END;

DECLARE 
L_NAME_VALUE VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN

SELECT L_NAME INTO L_NAME_VALUE 
FROM
(SELECT L_NAME FROM NEW_TABLE
ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
WHERE rownum = 1;
END;

DECLARE 
BORN_DATE_VALUE DATE;
BEGIN
BORN_DATE_VALUE :=TO_DATE(TRUNC(
DBMS_RANDOM.value(
TO_CHAR(date '1870-01-01','J')
,TO_CHAR(date '1995-01-01','J')
)),'J');
END;


INSERT INTO STUDENT(ID_STUDENT,F_NAME,L_NAME,BORN_DATE)
VALUES (S_STUD.NEXTVAL,F_NAME_VALUE,L_NAME_VALUE, BORN_DATE_VALUE);
-------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
2 TABLE DOCUMENTS
*/
DECLARE 
ENTERED_DATE_VALUE DATE;
BEGIN
ENTERED_DATE_VALUE :=TO_DATE(TRUNC(
DBMS_RANDOM.value(
TO_CHAR(date '1870-01-01','J')
,TO_CHAR(date '1995-01-01','J')
)),'J');
END;

DECLARE 
FINISHED_DATE_VALUE DATE;
BEGIN
FINISHED_DATE_VALUE :=TO_DATE(TRUNC(
DBMS_RANDOM.value(
TO_CHAR(date '1870-01-01','J')
,TO_CHAR(date '1995-01-01','J')
)),'J');
END;

INSERT INTO DOCUMENTS(DOC_ID,ENTERED, FINISHED, ID_STUDENT)
VALUES(S_DOC.NEXTVAL,ENTERED_DATE_VALUE, FINISHED_DATE_VALUE,                                      S_STUD.CURRVAL);
------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
3 TABLE ACCEPTANCE
*/


DECLARE 
UNIVERSITY_NAME_VALUE VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN     
SELECT UNIVERSITY INTO UNIVERSITY_NAME_VALUE 
FROM
(SELECT UNIVERSITY FROM NEW_TABLE
ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
WHERE rownum = 1; 
END;

DECLARE 
FACULTY_NAME_VALUE VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN 
SELECT FACULTY_NAME INTO FACULTY_NAME_VALUE
FROM
(SELECT FACULTY_NAME FROM NEW_TABLE
ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
WHERE rownum = 1; 
END;


INSERT INTO ACCEPT_RESULT(DETAIL_ID,UNIVERSITY_NAME,FACULTY_NAME,DOC_ID)
VALUES (S_ACCEPT.NEXTVAL,UNIVERSITY_NAME_VALUE, FACULTY_NAME_VALUE,       S_DOC.CURRVAL);
END LOOP;



END;
/

EXECUTE INSERT_DATA(15);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you checked with a `SELECT` to see an example of a year that is being passed?

Comment: I tried outputting the variable to console. Worked fine. Sample output:
`2007.05.21`

Comment: With `.` seperator this does not look like a valid date format.

Comment: The code as posted has some serious scoping problems, and it certainly would not compile for me. For example, 'F_NAME_VALUE' is declared in a block at line 11 of the procedure, and the block containing this variable is ended at line 19; however, `F_NAME_VALUE` is used again at line 44. Apparently the code was changed after it was used but prior to posting it here. An examination of the edit history of the question seems to bear this out. Please post code which will compile. Thanks.

Comment: The code was changed when I found a dumb mistake where I was using strings instead of variables in `INSERT` statements. Please, check the side-by-side markdown in the revision. Aside of that, are you saying I can't use my variables in the `INSERT` statement? How should I declare my variables, assign values for them and then insert these values in tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! My problem was that variables do not exist outside of their block:

```
DECLARE
...
BEGIN
END;
```

So I had to declare all variables that will be inserted into a table in one place and do the insertion in the same block. Here's the full working code:

```
DROP TABLE ACCEPT_RESULT;
DROP TABLE DOCUMENTS;
DROP TABLE STUDENT;
DROP TABLE NEW_TABLE;
DROP SEQUENCE S_ACCEPT;
DROP SEQUENCE S_DOC;
DROP SEQUENCE S_STUD;


CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(ID_STUDENT NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
F_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
L_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
BORN_DATE DATE
);


CREATE TABLE DOCUMENTS
(
DOC_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
ENTERED DATE,
FINISHED DATE,
ID_STUDENT NUMBER REFERENCES STUDENT(ID_STUDENT)
);


CREATE TABLE ACCEPT_RESULT
(DETAIL_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
UNIVERSITY_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
FACULTY_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
DOC_ID NUMBER REFERENCES DOCUMENTS(DOC_ID)
);


CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE
(
F_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
L_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
UNIVERSITY VARCHAR2(50),
FACULTY_NAME VARCHAR2(30)
);


INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('AGNE', 'AGNAITE', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('INGRIDA', 'INGRIDAITE', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('ANTANAS', 'ANTANAITIS', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('BRONIUS', 'BRONEVICIUS', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('LIEPA', 'LIEPAITE', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('AGNE', 'TAUTAVICIUTE', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('ILONA', 'SILAITE', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('AKVILE', 'GEDRIMAITE', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('ANDRIUS', 'STONKUS', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('GRETA', 'GRETAITE', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('KASPARAS', 'NACIUS', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('ROKAS', 'DARGEVICIUS', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('JUSTINAS', 'ENGELAITIS', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('VALIUS', 'DUMBRAUSKAS', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('EDGARAS', 'GVOZDAS', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('ANTANAS', 'JASAITIS', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('LINAS', 'STARKUTIS', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('AURIMAS', 'GEDMINTAS', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('LINAS', 'LINAITIS', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('LINAS', 'LINELIS', 'KLAIPEDA STATE UNIVERSITY OF APPLIED SCIENCES', 'TECHNOLOGY');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('KRUMAS', 'TADAS', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('MElynas', 'Tadas', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Raudonas', 'Tomas', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Zalias', 'Karolis', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Geltonas', 'Robertas', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('OranZinis', 'Rokas', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Juodas', 'Justinas', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Pilkas', 'Ignas', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Dariauskas', 'Darius', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Kairys', 'Jurgis', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('DeSinytE', 'Ruta', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('VySniauskas', 'Petras', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('SiemaitE', 'Aurelija', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('GirtauskaitE', 'Ieva', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Piemenaitis', 'Audrius', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Grybas', 'Karolis', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('EkranaviCius', 'Tomas', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Klavauskas', 'Antanas', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('ZiurkytE', 'Sandra', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Kaleimauskas', 'Domas', 'KLAIPEDA UNIVERSITY', 'SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('BlaiveviCius',   'Haroldas', 'KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('PelytE', '   AuSra','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('MeSkaitE', ' Viktorija','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Vilkas', '   Kęstas','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('KrUmas', '   ArUnas','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Medis', '    ArtUras','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('ObuolaitE', 'Ingrida','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('GaidauskienE', 'EglE','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('ZuvienE', 'Monika','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('MorkaviCius', 'Tadas','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('DeSrytE', 'Kornelija','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('SUris', 'Aurimas','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('BandelE', 'Greta','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('RUkaviCius', 'Edgaras','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Kreivauskas', 'Mantas','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('AklaitE', 'Diana','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Nekalbys', 'Rytis','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Telefonas', 'Deividas','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('LentaitE', 'Gabija','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('Viniauskas', 'Hermanas','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES ('MALKA', 'TOMAS','KAUNAS UNIVERSITY OF TECHNOLOGY', 'MEDICINE');




CREATE SEQUENCE S_STUD;
CREATE SEQUENCE S_DOC;
CREATE SEQUENCE S_ACCEPT;




CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_DATA(HOW_MANY_RECORDS NUMBER) IS
BEGIN


/*
1 TABLE STUDENT
*/


FOR I IN 1..HOW_MANY_RECORDS LOOP


DECLARE
F_NAME_VALUE VARCHAR2(20);
L_NAME_VALUE VARCHAR2(20);
BORN_DATE_VALUE DATE;

BEGIN
SELECT F_NAME INTO F_NAME_VALUE
FROM
(SELECT F_NAME FROM NEW_TABLE
ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
WHERE rownum = 1;

SELECT L_NAME INTO L_NAME_VALUE
FROM
(SELECT L_NAME FROM NEW_TABLE
ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
WHERE rownum = 1;

BORN_DATE_VALUE := TO_DATE(TRUNC(
DBMS_RANDOM.value(
TO_CHAR(date '1870-01-01','J')
,TO_CHAR(date '1995-01-01','J')
)),'J');

INSERT INTO STUDENT(ID_STUDENT,F_NAME,L_NAME,BORN_DATE)
VALUES (S_STUD.NEXTVAL,F_NAME_VALUE,L_NAME_VALUE,BORN_DATE_VALUE);

END; 
------------------------------------------------------------------- 

/*
2 TABLE DOCUMENTS
*/

DECLARE
ENTERED_DATE_VALUE DATE;
FINISHED_DATE_VALUE DATE;
BEGIN

ENTERED_DATE_VALUE :=TO_DATE(TRUNC(
DBMS_RANDOM.value(
TO_CHAR(date '1870-01-01','J')
,TO_CHAR(date '1995-01-01','J')
)),'J');

FINISHED_DATE_VALUE :=TO_DATE(TRUNC(
DBMS_RANDOM.value(
TO_CHAR(date '1870-01-01','J')
,TO_CHAR(date '1995-01-01','J')
)),'J');

INSERT INTO DOCUMENTS(DOC_ID,ENTERED, FINISHED, ID_STUDENT)
VALUES(S_DOC.NEXTVAL,ENTERED_DATE_VALUE, FINISHED_DATE_VALUE, S_STUD.CURRVAL);

END; 
------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
3 TABLE ACCEPTANCE
*/

DECLARE
UNIVERSITY_NAME_VALUE VARCHAR2(50);
FACULTY_NAME_VALUE VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN    
SELECT UNIVERSITY INTO UNIVERSITY_NAME_VALUE
FROM
(SELECT UNIVERSITY FROM NEW_TABLE
ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
WHERE rownum = 1;

SELECT FACULTY_NAME INTO FACULTY_NAME_VALUE
FROM
(SELECT FACULTY_NAME FROM NEW_TABLE
ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
WHERE rownum = 1;

INSERT INTO ACCEPT_RESULT(DETAIL_ID,UNIVERSITY_NAME,FACULTY_NAME,DOC_ID)
VALUES (S_ACCEPT.NEXTVAL,UNIVERSITY_NAME_VALUE, FACULTY_NAME_VALUE, S_DOC.CURRVAL);

END;

END LOOP;

END;
/

EXECUTE INSERT_DATA(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ? to generate random date

```
 declare
 a date;
 begin                                                                                                                  
  --  for i in 1..5                                                                                                          
  --  loop                                                                                                                   
a  := trunc(sysdate + dbms_random.value(0,366)) ;                                   
 --end loop;
 dbms_output.put_line(a);  
end;                                                                                                                   
/
```

**EXECUTION:**

```
SQL> @seq.sql                                                                                                               
20-MAY-16                                                                                                                   

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.                                                                                    

SQL> @seq.sql                                                                                                               
10-NOV-15                                                                                                                   

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.                                                                                    

SQL> @seq.sql                                                                                                               
09-JUN-15                                                                                                                   

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Weird, now, that you edited, it works. But if I try to run only the 4th line, it says unknown command.

Comment: Try assigning to a variable , Since you can't use the 4th line as is.

Comment: Allright, I am able to get a date, but now I get some other errors. I posted my current full code here (error code at the end) : http://pastebin.com/4384a3fY

Comment: It is better to add EXCEPTIONS in your procedure (INSERT_DATA) This will tell you exactly what went wrong and fix the errors.

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR MESSAGE :' || SQLCODE || ' :' || SQLERRM );

Comment: I've put that line at the end of my procedure, right after `END LOOP;` but I am getting no new output.